# What is the minimum core module set necessary for developing custom application with Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I need to develop a custom application using the Magento 2 framework. What are the minimum core modules necessary to achieve this?

Comment: u can find it in https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/Umc_Base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation for now is to use all of the modules which are provided out of the box with the Magento 2.

There is an attempt to allocate Magento composer components per "bundles" for the case if you need let's say just framework or just Catalog, etc, but there are still a lot of work to achieve it mostly because of the dependencies between modules.

You can try to disable certain modules which you sure you don't need, following instructions in this guide
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html
The tool will highlight the dependencies which might prevent from doing this.